# Programmatically convert Excel 2003 files to 2007+

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I'm looking for a way to essentially take a folder of excel files that are the old 2003 file extension .xls and convert them into .xlsm.  I realize you can go into the excel sheet yourself and manually do it, but is there anyway to do it with code?  Specifically using any sort of library?

Comment: @paqogomez ; this requires to have installation of MS office 2007 to use these interop libraries

Comment: @ManishJain, if you follow the link i provided, you'll see that you're able to download them without having installed ms office

Comment: @paqogomez I got "We're sorry, this download is no longer available. " when following link posted by you. Please check and provide another.

Comment: @ManishJain sure enough.  It must have disappeared only days ago because it was up when I checked it earlier this month.  Probably support for 2007 has been dropped.  [The 2010 files are available however.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508)  If you really need the 2007, you'll probably have to find it from a non official source.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is not my code, but I have used ClosedXML before and it is awesome. I found this on the FAQ asking if it supports Excel 2003 which looks like it should work for you...

To clarify, this uses the Office Interop library not closedXML, but I mentioned it incase you had any additional modifications you needed.

```
public void Convert(String filesFolder)
{
     files = Directory.GetFiles(filesFolder);

     var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
     var wb = app.Workbooks.Open(file);
     wb.SaveAs(Filename: file + "x", FileFormat: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);
     wb.Close();
     app.Quit();
}
```

[Here is the link](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Does%20it%20support%20Excel%202003%20and%20prior%20formats%20%28.xls%29%3F&referringTitle=Documentation)

hope it helps :D

Comment: Keep in mind that Interop requires Excel installed on the server, and this won't work on Azure.

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375943/how-to-create-an-instance-of-excel-if-excel-is-not-installed