# Error when trying to read an .xls file using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

The following code is working fine for .xlsx, but it's not working for .xls. I got this error message

> Can not open the package. Package is an OLE compound document. If this is an encrypted package, please supply the password

**Code**

```
string filepath = txtBrowse.Text;

FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
//1. Reading from a binary Excel file ('97-2003 format; *.xls)
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);

FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(filepath);

using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
    string sheetName = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

    foreach (OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet sheet in package.Workbook.Worksheets)
    {
        // Check the name of the current sheet
        if (sheet.Name == sheetName)
        {
            package.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete(sheetName);
            break; // Exit the loop now
        }
    }

    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
}
```

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: This also shows up as an index out of bounds error when you access `package.Workbook.Worksheets[1]`

Answer (score 29):

EPPlus does not work with the XLS format. Only XLSX. You'll need to find a new library.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. But can you suggest any one which is easy for reading and process the excel. Because my project completed so i want to edit some code of epplus only.

Answer (score 7):

I succesfully used Tony's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18904633/306515 and simply convert it using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and can still then use epplus