# EPPlus excel read IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I want to read data from excel (.xlsx or .xls) file
I am using EPPlus 
but it give that error IndexOutOfRangeException: Worksheet position out of range.
in this line

```
  OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
```

here is my all code.Here is my excel file for redad(http://yazilimsozluk.com/a.xlsx )
.Are there any solution for excel read which works with .xlsx and .xls excel file?

```
if (Request != null) {
  HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["UploadedFile"];
  if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName)) {
    string fileName = file.FileName;
    string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
    var data = file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));


    var existingFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName);
    var package = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(existingFile);

    OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

    for (int i = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Column; i <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Column; i++) {
      for (int j = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Row; j <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row; j++) {
        object cellValue = workSheet.Cells[i, j].Value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have a choice, just check for xls / xlsx and inform the user that you don't support xls. If you don't have a choice, you may have to go with some commercial library... honestly the free ones for xls never really worked for me - the support is a lot better for xlsx. Maybe you are lucky and someone has a better idea

Comment: Ok I can inform user but .xlsx does not work,it give same error

Comment: Just so we are clear: please make sure you can open the specific file in excel without any warning message before you complain about errors when trying to use the same file with other programs.

Comment: I can open without any warning....should I install openoffice to my pc ?

Comment: Are we still talking about the linked example (http://yazilimsozluk.com/a.xlsx)? That shouldn't be accepted by excel without complaint.

Comment: In my pc it opened without complaint,may be differecen version?

Answer (score 2):

First of all EPPlus can not handle .xls files. See this answer:

[Error when trying to read an .xls file using EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152215/error-when-trying-to-read-an-xls-file-using-epplus)

Sample code for reading a file:

```
var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("sample.xlsx"));

ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();

for (int i = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Column;
        i <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
        i++)
{
    for (int j = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Row;
            j <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
            j++)
    {
        object cellValue = workSheet.Cells[i, j].Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: your code give error( Worksheet position out of range. ).Here is my excell file: http://yazilimsozluk.com/a.xlsx

Comment: That file is a renamed `.html`-file. `<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`. Fix: Rename to `.xls`, open it in Excel and then save as `xlsx`.

Comment: @user1688401 Updated, now it works. Try replacing `Worksheets[0];` with `Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();` in your code.

Comment: It works but it is null for me...Did you try with this ? yazilimsozluk.com/a.xlsx

Comment: @user1688401 Use my code, I get values. Got your file, converted it to `.xlsx` and could then read values. Here is the converted file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/30crslyowk6u2cw/a.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: I download your file but some code does not work for me..I has office 2003 maybe because of this ?

Comment: @user1688401 Could give you an error if you try to open the file but if you run my code it should work. Anyway 2003 will remove some XML-tags I think even if you have the Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack. If you need to handle modern files you really should upgrade. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3

Comment: I am sure your path for the file is wrong because i faced the same issue and unfortunately i was providing wrong path of the excel file to Read. When i gave the correct path the issue fixed.